# Combining Refresh Tokens with Facebook / Google in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, access-token

I've implemented external login providers in webapi by following this tutorial:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/

I wanted to also include refresh tokens to this solution. I managed to follow this article to do that in regular login scenario - http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that for external logins. I've looked into implementation of OWIN and tried doing something like the code below. It generates tokens but I have trouble serializing ticket (ticket can't be unprotected when I try to make a request to generate new access token based on the refresh token generated this way).

```
private async Task<JObject> GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(string userId)
{
    var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    var user = await GetUser(userId);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
    };

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);

    var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

    // This is what I added
    var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
    // Here I use a DataProtectionProvider which I generated on startup with app.GetDataProtectionProvider() and I keep it as a static object
    var secureDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(Helpers.Providers.DataProtectionProvider.Create(
        typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace, "Refresh_Token", "v1", "ASP.NET Identity"));

    var createContext = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(context, secureDataFormat, ticket);
    await Startup.OAuthServerOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(createContext);

    JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
        new JProperty("userName", user.UserName),
        new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
        new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
        new JProperty("expires_in", tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
        new JProperty(".issued", ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString()),
        new JProperty(".expires", ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString()),
        new JProperty("refresh_token", createContext.Token)
        );

    return tokenResponse;
}
```